# Audio glitches. Puppeteer, Chromium, Node js server, Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, puppeteer, chromium

Looking for advice/help.

I am using puppeteer to automate playing my web-player (wrote on js with Howler library).

When I manually open Chromium, then go to http://localhost:8080 and click on #play-button - music plays well.
When I reproduce such a behaviour with puppeteer - I am getting glitches, pausing (even for 1-2sec) during playing.
Don't know how to solve it and where to look for an answer.
I am using pre-installed Chromium (v 88.0.4324.127) on my Raspberry Pi.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Turn on http-server on node js (goal - serving local music mp3 files)
2. Run puppeteer script in headless or headful mode. (command in terminal "node puppeteer-script.js". tried also with "&" at the end - didnt work, everything stoped after 10-30 seconds)

Puppeteer script itself:

```
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer-core');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch ({
        headless: false,
        executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
    await page.goto('http://localhost:8080');
    await page.setCacheEnabled(false);
    
    await page.waitForSelector('#play-button').then(()=> page.click('#play-button'));

})();
```

Bassicaly my Player plays one song after another, has crossfade at the end of current song (so there are mixing for couple seconds).
Player script itself (I'm using Howler.js library):

```
function loadingSound1 (i, playingList) {
        var intervaller;

        sound1 = new Howl ({
            src: [playingList[i]],
            preload: true,
            html5: true,
            onplay: function() {
                        var time1 = sound1.duration();
                        var timetoswitch1 = time1 - fadeTime;

                        intervaller = setInterval(() => {
                            if (sound1.seek() >= timetoswitch1) {
                                sound2.play();
                                clearInterval(intervaller);
                            };
                        },500);                     
                        },
            onpause: function () {clearInterval(intervaller)},          
            onend: function () {
                        console.log('i = ' + i + 'k = ' + k);

                        sound1.unload();

                        listLength = playingList.length;
                        i = i + 2;
                        loadingSound1 (i, playingList);     
            }
        })
}

function loadingSound2 (k, playingList) {
        var intervaller;

        sound2 = new Howl ({
            src: [playingList[k]],
            preload: true,
            html5: true,
            onplay: function() {
                var time2 = sound2.duration();
                var timetoswitch2 = time2 - fadeTime;
                
                intervaller = setInterval(() => {

                    if (sound2.seek() >= timetoswitch2) {
                        sound1.play();
                        clearInterval(intervaller);
                                };
                        },500);                 
                    },
            onend: function () {
                        listLength = playingList.length;

                        sound2.unload();

                        k = k + 2;
                        loadingSound2 (k, playingList);
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This isn't reproducible because we don't have whatever the contents of localhost:8080 are. Can you share a [mcve] of the app you're automating? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen thank you for welcoming, thank you for noticing! ) added player script